# Чем отличается преобразование типов?

Tags: java, android, ооп

Только что случайно наткнулся на два вида преобразований (раньше даже внимания не обращал, что они разные и использовал первое преобразование для неприметивных объектов, с применением `instanceof`, а остальное — для преобразования примитивных):

1. `String text = (String) textField.getText();`
2. `String text = String.valueOf(textField.getText());`

Чем отличаются эти преобразования и есть ли сильные различия?

Comment: Второй вариант переводит любой тип в String. Это даже не приведение типа, а ПРЕДСТАВЛЕНИЕ параметра этой функции в виде строки. Первый же вариант - да, чистое "кастование"

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, пожалуйста, как ответ оформите свой комментарий :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Как говорится в ответе на [аналогичный вопрос на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815279/difference-between-casting-to-string-and-string-valueof):

Кастинг к строке работает, **только** если объект является строкой:

```
Object reallyAString = "foo";
String str = (String) reallyAString; // works.
```

И не работает, если объект — это что-то ещё:

```
Object notAString = new Integer(42);
String str = (String) notAString; // will throw a ClassCastException
```

В тоже время [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) пытается конвертировать к `String` всё, что ему передали. Он работает и с примитивами (42), и с объектами (new Integer(42), используя метод объектов [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)):

```
String str;
str = String.valueOf(new Integer(42)); // str will hold "42"
str = String.valueOf("foo"); // str will hold "foo"
Object nullValue = null;
str = String.valueOf(nullValue); // str will hold "null"
```

Обратите внимание на последний пример: при передаче `null` в `String.valueOf()` будет возвращена строка "null".

Answer (score 4):

Второй вариант переводит любой тип в String. Это даже не приведение типа, а ПРЕДСТАВЛЕНИЕ параметра этой функции в виде строки. Первый же вариант - да, чистое "кастование"

Comment: Эм... А чем представление отличается от "кастования"? Работают же одинаково.

Comment: @bukashka101 думаете, на любом параметре одинаково?